# What is the NDK and how can I use JNI?

Tags: android-ndk

hi give me simple explanation for ndk and jni i am not clear this topic explain what is the main purpose....i am fresher for android application help me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NDK = Native Development Kit
http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Basically: you can use parts C or C++ for your android develpment.

It's really hard to give a more basic explanation than this quote (from above link, with annotations in-between by me):

> Android applications run in the Dalvik virtual machine.

*Meaning: the Android variety of the Java Virtual machine (yes, that's a bit of a shortcut, but gimme a break :)  ) So normally you're making your code in JAVA, for this virtual machine.*

> The NDK allows you to implement parts of your applications using native-code languages such as C and C++.

*Now sometimes you have parts code (you might have developed earlier for another platform) that you want to re-use. And they're NOT in JAVA. Then you can use the NDK to incorporate them in your APK*.

> The NDK provides:
>
> - A set of tools and build files used to generate native code libraries
>     from C and C++ sources

*So you get tools to use your 'old' C/C++ sources as a base, and create libraries for you android app*.

> - A way to embed the corresponding native libraries into an application
>     package file (.apk) that can be deployed on Android devices

*Now you need more then just libraries. You also get a method to actually use them.*

Comment: i am already look at this link but i am not clear...confused me can u tell me simple explanation for the ndk main purpose

Comment: I can't get more clear then the changed answer above. You might want to actually pinpoint what you understand, and what not. If you're not clear on compilation, virtual machines (as in JVM / Dalvik VM) etc, you might want to get that clear before starting with the NDK questions :)